# Is there an alternative to Dictionary/SortedList that allows duplicates?

Tags: .net, dictionary, priority-queue, multimap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Sortable collection which allows duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716423/c-sharp-sortable-collection-which-allows-duplicate-keys)

Basically I'd like to make a Dictionary work with duplicate keys without going into custom comparer implementations. There is an idea of:

```
  Dictionary<key, List<value>>
```

but it still has some overhead. I wish Dictionary had "AllowDuplicates".

Comment: Didn't find that in my searches. Voted for close, thanks.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716423/c-sharp-sortable-collection-which-allows-duplicate-keys

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5 then [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) is probably what you're after.

Comment: It's a pity that such a potentially useful class has a few limitations. Such as no public constructor or ability to add/remove items.

Comment: @Ray, Agree completely. Although I guess that's why it's called Lookup rather than something like MultiDictionary, to hint that it's an immutable lookup of some sort rather than a collection to be manipulated. The OP's suggestion of a Dictionary<key, List<value>> would be much more flexible.

Comment: @Ray: The best constructor is, and i quote MSDN: "You can create an instance of a Lookup<TKey, TElement> by calling ToLookup on an object that implements IEnumerable<T>.

"

Answer (score 7):

.NET 2.0: [PowerCollections](http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=6863) contains the `OrderedMultiDictionary`.

Answer (score 4):

You still can use SortedList and try to make a unique key by combining your value and a Guid into a class. In this case, you must implement the `IComparer<NewKey>` for your new key, something like:

```
class MyKey
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public float Value { get; set; }
}

class MyComparer : IComparer<MyKey>
{

    public int Compare(MyKey x, MyKey y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("both of parameters must be not null");
        if (x.Value < y.Value) return -1;
        if (x.Value > y.Value) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and then

```
var mySortedList = new SortedList<MyKey, MyValue>(new MyComparer());
```

Answer (score 3):

Not in the Fx < 3.5..  You can implement one, obviously, with a Dictionary of IList objects.  But then you have the encapsulation issue/responsibility.

If you're using .NET 3.5, use the [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) class.

Comment: It's only a replacement for `Dictionary`, but not for `SortedList`.

Answer (score 2):

That does not work.  As soon as you return 0 from the comparer, it will throw "duplicate" exception.

You don't need classes encapsulation or anything, just make a comparer that does not return 0 (equal) result.  Here is an example for `int` type of key

```
class MyComparer : IComparer<int>
{

  public int Compare(int x, int y)
  {
    if (x < y)
      return -1;
    else return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this trick will break the indexer. If you try to get a value using the indexer you will get an exception because the key could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a Dictionary contains unique keys.  Your example above is effectively a sort of two-dimensional keyed array, a structure I've used many times.  Why would you want to have duplicate keys?  If you did, how would the Dictionary uniquely address its members?

Comment: Consider a real-world dictionary listing different meanings for the same word. Multiple entries with a common key. Nothing contradictory about that. Members could be addressed by a lookup returning a collection or Enumerable. C++ has had a multimap for ages. It's not an impossible problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I came across with same issue.. I needed a sortedList which can allow Duplicate Keys..

```
var sortList = new SortedList<string, IDictionary<string, object>>();
```

but this didnt work.. so i used

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, IDictionary<string, object>>>();
```

add new data to it as ..

```
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, IDictionary<string, object>>>(value, Dictionary));
```

with linq i sorted it with no problem..

Try `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, List<TValue>>>();`

Comment: Don't forget that this has O(N) lookup cost by key unlike an hashtable (or a dictionary), which is O(1) mostly.