# Adding more than one value to a single key in a hashtable in c#?

Tags: c#, hashtable

I'm trying to make a program where it reads strings that has a word and its meaning, for example

```
Book: Cover with Papers in between
Book: Reserve
```

And whenever I try my code I get an error because each key has to be unique. Is there a way to work around this?

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        var fileStream = new FileStream(@"e:\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {

            string line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                ht.Add(line.Split(':')[0], line.Split(':')[1]);
            }
        }

        if (ht.ContainsKey("Book"))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(ht["Book"].ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case, you could use a `List<string>` for the value, and just `Add` to it. However, you can probably simplify with LINQ via `ToLookup`:

```
var groups = File.ReadLines(path)
            .Select(line => line.Split(':'))
            .ToLookup(x => x[0], x => x[1].Trim());
```

Now you can access `groups[key]` which gives you all the values with that prefix, or you can `foreach` over `groups` to get each combination of `.Key` and values.

In terms of your code, this is:

```
var groups = File.ReadLines(@"e:\test.txt")
            .Select(line => line.Split(':'))
            .ToLookup(x => x[0], x => x[1].Trim());

foreach(var val in groups["Book"])
    listBox1.Items.Add(val);
```

(no need to check for existence first, it just works correctly if no match)

However! You only need to do this if you still want *all* the values *after* this code, i.e. you use `groups` somewhere else. If you don't, you can be more frugal and just abandon the unwanted data:

```
var values = File.ReadLines(@"e:\test.txt")
             .Where(line => line.StartsWith("Book:"))
             .Select(line => line.Substring(5).Trim());

foreach(var val in values)
    listBox1.Items.Add(val);
```

---

Edit: minor thing - a vexing method signature means that `line.Split(':')` actually creates an array every time, because `params`; so I usually use:

```
static readonly char[] Colon = {':'};
```

and

```
line.Split(Colon)
```

Which is measurably more efficient *if* it is a hot path.

Comment: Thank you, could you apply it to my code so I can see how it works please, as I'm still very new to this.

Comment: @Cor sure; but: if there are 2 lines with `Book` as the prefix, what value did you want to use in the listbox? all of them? or the first? or the last?

Comment: ♦ All of them, in our example 'book' has two meanings, i want to add both to the listbox. Thanks!

Comment: @Cor I've added two examples of doing that, depending on your exact needs

Answer (score 2):

Use a Dictionary where the values is a list of strings:

```
var myDicitonary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
```

And now, you'd do the following:

```
if (!myDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
{
    myDicitonary.Add(key, new List<string>());
}

myDicitonary[key].Add(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` instead of the Hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you may use a `SortedList` or a `SortedDictionary`, that you initialze with your own `IComparer`, which allows duplicate keys.
Have a look at these Stackoverflow posts for details:

[C# Sortable collection which allows duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716423/c-sharp-sortable-collection-which-allows-duplicate-keys)
[Is there an alternative to Dictionary/SortedList that allows duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551901/is-there-an-alternative-to-dictionary-sortedlist-that-allows-duplicates)

The drawback of this solution is, that you cannot access the elements by key, but still by index.

Answer (score 0):

use Dictionary instead.

```
Dictionary<string, list<string>> dic = new Dictionary<string, list<string>();
```